# Use hclust on upper triangle in R

Tags: r, hclust

I have a matrix like so:

```
  a b c
a 1 3 4
b 3 1 2
c 4 2 1
```

Is it possible to use `hclust` on the upper triangle without splicing the matrix diagonally?

```
structure(c(1, 3, 4, 3, 1, 2, 4, 2, 1), .Dim = c(3L, 3L), .Dimnames = list(c("a", "b", "c"), c("a", "b", "c")))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a coercion function, `as.dist`, that turns a matrix into the right class object for hclust:

```
> hclust( as.dist( m))

Call:
hclust(d = as.dist(m))

Cluster method   : complete 
Number of objects: 3
```